# If $\lvert f'(x)\rvert \leq M$ prove that $\lvert f(b)-f(a)\rvert \leq M(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the standard conditions, that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose also that $\lvert f'(x)\rvert \leq M$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Prove that $\lvert f(b)-f(a)\rvert \leq M(b-a)$. I have proven that $\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq M(b-a)$, can I use that in some way or should I focus in the given of $\lvert f'(x)\rvert \leq M$?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT.** Use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

$|f(b)-f(a)|=|\int_a^b f'(x)dx|\le \int_a^b|f'(x)|dx\le \int_a^bMdx=M(b-a)$.